# Stylish CSS has no effect? CSS Order in Stylish?

Tags: css, operator-precedence, stylish

This is the website's CSS:

```
.bam_announcement {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;-webkit-border-radius:5px
}
```

And this is my Stylish CSS:

```
.bam_announcement {
    -moz-border-radius:0px;-webkit-border-radius:0px
}
```

But the website is still using 5px.

Comment: Have you tried deleting your browser-cache?

Comment: Do you have dev-tools or firebug installed? If so, inspect the element that has the border-radius, and verify that this exact rule is active. Maybe some other selector in your css sets the 5px?

Comment: Your code is incomplete. You have a live example? Maybe you defined it somewhere else aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we can't be sure of the order that *Stylish* CSS will be applied -- relative to page CSS -- Stylish scripts often have to use the `!important` flag.

So make your Stylish CSS:

```
.bam_announcement {
    -moz-border-radius: 0px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

---

In the rare cases where that doesn't work, see: [How to override CSS Background that already has !important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416016/how-to-override-css-background-that-already-has-important) .